# Derived class from class instance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

how do I make a derived class which can change all the variables from an instance of its base class? I understand I could declare the base class variables static, but when I do that I cannot initialise them using functions, which makes the code very message and difficult to edit.

This an example class; why does c2 not edit x in the theC1 class. If it is referencing to a c1 class which is not theC1, then what is is referencing to?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class c1
{
public:
    c1( int d )
    {
        x = d;
    }
    int x;
};

class c2 : public c1
{
public:
    c2( c1& ref )
        :
    c1( ref )
    {};
    void setx()
    {
        x = 5;
    }
};

int main () 
{
    c1 theC1(4);
    c2 theC2(theC1);
    theC2.setx();

    printf( "%d\n",theC1.x );
    printf( "%d\n",theC2.x );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That should not even compile... or at least give loads of warnings.

Comment: @fredrik: Actually it's perfectly valid. It's not nice, and it includes C headers, but it is perfectly valid and will compile without any error or warnings.

Comment: well, there is no copy constructor in the base class. But perhaps the compiler creates it automatically.

Comment: i think (most probably) you're just confusing instances with classes. like confusing the concrete elephans Dumbo and Dorthe with respectively African Elephant and general Elephant. Why are changes to Dumbo not reflected in Dorthe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theC1` and `theC2` are completely separate instances. `theC2` contains a subobject of type `c1` which is initialised by the reference `ref`, but it's still (and always will be) a different instance of `c1` than `theC1`. The base class subobject is a member of every `c2` instance and there's no way to make this "shared" with any other instance of `c2` or `c1`.

You could store the reference inside `c2` and access that instead of deriving from `c1` if that is the semantics you're after. The code would then look like this:

```
class c1
{
public:
    c1( int d )
    {
        x = d;
    }
    int x;
};

class c2
{
    c1 &myC1;
public:
    c2( c1& ref )
        :
    myC1(ref)
    , x(myC1.x)
    {}
    void setx()
    {
        myC1.x = 5;
    }
    int &x;
};
```

Of course, it would be better to encapsulate `x`, rather than have it public and have to resort to reference tricks like those in the code above.

**UPDATE**

One way to implement this on a larger scale could be `c1` and `c2` implementing the same interface, and `c2` instances sharing a "data instance" of `c1`:

```
#include <memory>


struct c1_iface
{
  virtual int getX() const = 0;
  virtual void setX(int newX) = 0;
};


class c1 : public c1_iface
{
  int x;

public:
  virtual int getX() const { return x; }
  virtual void setX(int newX) { x = newX; }
};


class c2 : public c1_iface
{
  std::shared_ptr<c1> data_;

public:
  explicit c2(std::shared_ptr<c1> data) : data_(data) {}

  virtual int getX() const { return data_->getX(); }
  virtual void setX(int newX) { data_->setX(newX); }
};
```

If you don't have access to C++11, you can use `boost::shared_ptr` instead (or just use manual sharing, not really recommended).

As a slightly dirtier alternative, you could move the shared pointer (or its equivalent) into `c1_iface` and make the functions non-abstract, dereferencing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's the sort of thing I want to do, except a little cleaner. If there is no way of having derived classes share variables in a base class instance, what would be the best way of having lots of classes access the variables of a class c1 instance?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a reference to call the copy constructor of `c1`, not saving a reference to a `c1` object. You want something like this:

```
class c2 : public c1
{
public:
    c2( c1& ref )
        : c1_ptr(&ref) {}

    void setx()
    {
        c1_ptr->x = 5;
        this->x   = 5;
    }
private:
    c1 * c1_ptr;
};
```

However, this needs a default-constructor for `c1`. If you don't want any construction at all, you might want to use a proxy class:

```
class c1_proxy
{
public:
    c1_proxy( c1& ref )
        : x(ref.x), c1_ptr(&ref) {}

    void setx()
    {
        c1_ptr->x = 5;        
    }
    int & x;
private:
    c1 * c1_ptr;
};
```

However, I consider this as an antipattern. Note that you have to update all values by hand.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I tried that but it says there is no default constructor for c1. The problem is I don't want to construct a c1, i just want to reference or point to an instance of c1.

Comment: @user2243911: This could happen because I haven't called the correct constructor of `c1`, see Angew's answer. If you don't want to construct a `c1` at all you shouldn't inherit from it.